# Lookup and return multiple matches in a new table

Tags: excel, vba

I have been stuck on this for weeks and have tried many formula combinations but can't get this to work.  I don't know VBA so don't know where to start there.

I have List 1 and List 2 below.  I need List 3 to be created from the data in Lists 1 and 2.  List 3 can, preferably, be created in a new sheet.

I need to lookup the criteria from Column A, in List2 (Column D) then return all matches in a new list that shows: List 1; the criteria (Column A),  data in Column B; and all matches from List 2 (Column E)

See Below.   List 3 is the outcome

[image]

I broke this into two parts and I tried using a formula that copied the row the amount of times that there was a match.  Then I was going to copy paste or find some vba or formula to combine the table but I came to a dead end when I realized the they tables weren't sorted in the same order.  I ended up with these two lists to combine

[image]

Tried this VBA
[image]
Getting this error

[image]

Comment: Do you mind a VBA solution? I'm not a fan of index/match formulas, though I imagine that'd be how you'd do it.

Comment: Yes please a VBA is what I need.  I just don't know how to write it myself

Comment: Let me know if you need any help with my answer

Comment: I believe you're getting this area BECAUSE you only have one sheet. It's trying to put it on `Sheet2` and you only have `Sheet1`

Comment: Your solution worked!  Thank you!  Not sure how it disappeared from here.... I ended up running it to be broken into 6 spearate sheets within the same workbook.

Comment: commonly known as full outer join https://www.google.com/search?q=full+outer+join+excel https://superuser.com/questions/1023123/how-to-simulate-a-full-outer-join-in-excel

Comment: @Elissa Glad it worked for you! I undeleted my answer - didn't think it would work with your giant data range. :) glad to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This.

Run the macro "Test"

The first parameter should be the range of your first list (Just the numbers)

The second parameter should be the range of your second list (Just the numbers)

OutputSheet should be the sheet you want to output the list on

You can also optionally set the output row and output column (It will start at `A1` if you don't specify)

```
Sub CreateList(List1 As Range, List2 As Range, OutputSheet As Worksheet, Optional ORow As Long = 1, Optional OCol As Long = 1)
Dim c, d
For Each c In List1
    For Each d In List2
        If c = d Then
            OutputSheet.Cells(ORow, OCol).Value = c.Value
            OutputSheet.Cells(ORow, OCol + 1).Value = c.Offset(0, 1).Value
            OutputSheet.Cells(ORow, OCol + 2).Value = d.Offset(0, 1).Value
            ORow = ORow + 1
        End If
    Next d
Next c
End Sub

Sub Test()
With Sheets("Sheet1")
    CreateList .Range("A2:A7"), .Range("D2:D6"), Sheets("Sheet2")
End With
End Sub
```

The code loops through each number in the first list, and then each number in the second list.

If the numbers are the same, it outputs the number, the item, and the price.

First it will check `If 10 = 10 Then` - output the number, output the text next to the number on the first list, and output the amount next to the number on the second list.

Then it increases the row by 1.

That's pretty much all there is to it - just make sure you specify the ranges properly and change the sheet references as needed.

If you have never used VBA before, you can open the window by pressing `ALT+F11`

Right click to the left side and select `Insert -> Module`

Paste the code into the right side.

Update the ranges on the following line so they match where your lists are:

`CreateList .Range("A2:A7"), .Range("D2:D6"), Sheets("Sheet2")`

You can then close the window and press `ALT+F8` to open the Run Macro dialog.

Select Test and click Run

[image: Help]

Input:

[image: Input]

Results:

[image: Results]

Comment: Ok.  I started over in a new workbook and no error messages this time...

Comment: It work for you? Judging by your screenshot, it looks like you accidentally pasted part of the code in a separate module, and you put the actual code in `Sheet5` instead of a module

Comment: I started over in a new Workbook with only the one sheet of data but now I am getting a different message.  I'll put the mscreenshot on the post (Don't know how to do it in comments)

Comment: Okay, when you put the code in, pay close attention to the line in the `test` macro. `With Sheets("Sheet1") CreateList .Range("A2:A7"), .Range("D2:D6"), Sheets("Sheet2") End With` What this is saying is "My data is on `Sheet1` - First list is `Range("A2:A7")` - second list is `Range("D2:D6")` - I want you to put it on `Sheet2`

Comment: You can also add other parameters telling it what `Row` and `Column` to start on (For example - `CreateList .Range("A2:A7"), .Range("D2:D6"), Sheets("Sheet2"), 1, 5` will put it in Row 1, Column 5 - though I really should've made it a variant so you don't have to do it by number - but you get the idea.

Comment: Oh yes I forgot to open a second sheet in the new workbook.  Trying again

Comment: One more thought - the ranges you're using look absolutely huge. Are you sure the list will even fit in excel? It only handles `1,048,576` rows - your second set looks like it has at least `100k` and it's just going to grow.

Comment: If you have that much data - should really be written using arrays - it's going to take forever since the first set loops through every single version of the second set.

Comment: I was just thinking the same thing when excel froze.  I am going to try breaking it into a few different workbooks and hopefully that helps

Comment: Yikes - at those scales the macro needs to be refactored - It might take a bit with a couple thousand rows, but it'll take a lot longer with that much data.

Comment: If you're still around tomorrow I will help you out

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

The code below assumes that on Sheet1, data starts from Row2 where Row1 is the header row.

```
Sub CreateList()
Dim x, y, z()
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, n As Long, dlr As Long
Dim wsData As Worksheet, wsOutput As Worksheet
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set wsData = Sheets("Sheet1")
On Error Resume Next
Set wsOutput = Sheets("List")
wsOutput.Cells.Clear
On Error GoTo 0
If wsOutput Is Nothing Then
    Sheets.Add(after:=wsData).Name = "List"
    Set wsOutput = ActiveSheet
End If
x = wsData.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
y = wsData.Range("D1").CurrentRegion.Value

For i = 2 To UBound(x, 1)
    If Application.CountIf(wsData.Columns("D"), x(i, 1)) > 0 Then
        n = Application.CountIf(wsData.Columns("D"), x(i, 1))
        ReDim z(1 To n)
        k = 1
        For j = 2 To UBound(y, 1)
            If y(j, 1) = x(i, 1) Then
                z(k) = y(j, 2)
                k = k + 1
            End If
        Next j
        dlr = wsOutput.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(3)(2).Row
        wsOutput.Range("A" & dlr).Value = x(i, 1)
        wsOutput.Range("B" & dlr).Value = x(i, 2)
        wsOutput.Range("C" & dlr).End(3)(2).Resize(UBound(z, 1), 1) = Application.Transpose(z)
    End If
    Erase z
Next i
dlr = wsOutput.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(3)(2).Row
If dlr > 1 Then
    wsOutput.Range("A2:C" & dlr).CurrentRegion.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"
    wsOutput.Rows(1).Delete
End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

[image]

[image]